# React: Axios response loading on Console but not in DOM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios

I'm working on a project and I want to obtain only 1 object from GET (using id). It loads correctly on console.log but not on DOM, even using React.useState() and React.useEffect(). But it works well on process like list and create...
I've saw another question here about the same, but their answer didn't apply to my case...
So I would be very grateful if someone could enlighten me here.

---

**EDIT:**
And... after trying with another api, it seems is the current api I'm using... I'm not sure what authorizations need to be done since GET for listing and POST for creating are working well... Is there any axios authorization problem (that need to be done on backend) that if not checked it doesn't shows on DOM? (The original project backend is hosted on Heroku)

---

##### Example Code

**api.ts**

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://url.../api/";

const responseBody = <t>(response: AxiosResponse<t>) => response.data;
const request = {
    get: <t>(url: string) => axios.get<t>(url).then(responseBody),
    post: <t>(url: string, body: {}) => axios.post<t>(url, body).then(responseBody),
    put: <t>(url: string, body: {}) => axios.put<t>(url, body).then(responseBody),
    delete: <t>(url: string) => axios.delete<t>(url).then(responseBody),
};

export default request;
```

**apiArtist.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Artist } from "../models/artist";
import request from './api';
const apiArtist = {
    list: () => request.get<Artist[]>("/Artist"),
    add: (data: Artist) => request.post("/Artist", data),
    edit: (data: Artist) => request.put(`/Artist/${data.id}`, data),
    delete: (id: number) => request.delete(`/Artist/${id}`),
    detail: (id: number) => request.get<Artist>(`/Artist/${id}`),
};
```

**try.ts** (Component file)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Artist } from '../../models/artist';

export function Try(props:any) {
  const [artist, setArtist] = React.useState<Artist>(new Artist());
  function refreshArtist(id:number){
    apiArtist.detail(id).then((res)=>{
        setArtist(res);
        console.log('i artist:',res); //it shows correctly on Console
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    refreshArtist(12); //using raw id since I know it should retrieve success
  },[]); // I've also tried here with:
//[artist] //it's like a while true on Console but doesn't update on DOM
//[artist.username] -->executes 2 times like the next 2 ones
//[artist.username===undefined,artist.username===""] (and them alone)
//[artist.username!==undefined,artist.username!==""] (and them alone)
//even without the last param...  React.useEffect(()=>{ ... });
  
  return (<>
      <div>
        <h2>Doing stuff with data</h2>
        {artist.username}  <- it stills doesnt's show up here
        {artist.name} <- neither here
      </div>
  </>)
};
```

I know the backend works well since I'm able to check the correct response on console...
But I don't know why it doesn't update on DOM. (on {artist.username} and {artist.name})

Comment: I've also tried using alert(artist); after the console.log to check, and it shows undefined... but is just defined... :/

Comment: on line n.8 of "try.ts" did you try res.data instead of res? are you sure the res it's already the data you want?

Comment: I also thought that, but on the first file request already casts the data obtained to the type of object I need. (And since I'm using typescript, if I put res. it shows me the object properties like username and name.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  setArtist(() => res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create `new Artist()` and load `Artist` from `res` and do the `setArtist(artist)`

```
const [artist, setArtist] = React.useState<Artist>(new Artist());
function refreshArtist(id:number){
    apiArtist.detail(id).then((res)=>{
        let artist = new Artist();
        artist.username = res.username;
        artist.name = res.name;
        setArtist(artist);
        console.log('i artist:',res); //it shows correctly on Console
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: In the class Artist, I set "" on strings by default and 0 on ints... Now with
let artist = new Artist();
artist.username = res.username;
artist.name = res.name;
setArtist(artist);
console.log('i artist:',artist,res);
In console, res prints well still (succes and data) but now artist.username and artist.name are undefined...

Comment: if your res is ok and you bind data from res to artist then it should be ok. if not can you please prepare your code in codesandbox? so that I can run your code and find the issue.

Comment: OMG I just tried it but with a raw json file since with the real api it shows a network error (because authorizations) and it works... (https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dawn-n0y48?file=/src/App.tsx) I'm gonna cry, it just frustates me even more.... Does it has something to do with the libraries or something? I don't know... 
dependencies: yarn, react-router-dom, @types/react-router-dom, @mui/material
@mui/icons-material, @emotion/react @emotion/styled, @createnl/grouped-checkboxes, axios

Comment: Still, thank you! I just tried using the same raw file on the real project and it shows it well.... So, now I'm not sure... it has to do something with authorization? Or is it the local file loading fast or something?... Oh... I'm gonna check with another api to see if that's the case...

Comment: you are welcome :)